# How to display Cesium(JS) app in a blazor razor page

Tags: blazor, cesiumjs

I am trying to display a cesium app(https://cesium.com/platform/cesiumjs/)  made from javascript to be displayed in a blazor razor page.

These are the steps I followed

1. Copied Cesium script folder to wwwroot
   [Cesium folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaaBs.png)
2. Referenced it in the wwwroot/index.html file.

```
    <link href="Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <script>const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");</script>
```

3. Add the element in the razor page.

```
@page "/cesium"

<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>

@code {

}
```

After these steps I cannot see the cesium displayed in the razor page. Am I missing some steps?

Comment: Did you write any CSS to make `cesiumContainer` fill up some amount of space on the screen?  If not, the viewer will be zero size.

Answer (score -2):

You razor page should be this:

```
@page "/cesium"
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender){
        if (firstRender){
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("start");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why should the razor page be as you said. What is so special about this code snippet? I recommended deletion of your answer. As it stands now, your answer very unclear.